# How do I switch animations in Unity correctly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

How do I switch animations correctly?
I read about the division of responsibilities in different ways, about all sorts of abstractions, and I ran into the following problem:
I have a class that I want to control animations, how to do it correctly? (for convenience, the class that is responsible for animations will be called AnimClass)
AnimClass has several animations, for convenience, let it be running, calm, jumping.
Let me turn on animations via bool or trigger, and then how?
If I want to access AnimClass from another script and try to call animation, then I need to make a method with the appropriate name in AmimClass for each animation so that I can conveniently access it (because I do not know from another script about the list of animations that are in AnimClass and will have to access it through AnimClass(dot) and look at the list of methods and there is already a conditional void SetRunAnim, or I need to make a method in my AnimClass that will switch animations, cut down all unnecessary ones and turn on the transferred one, but then again I need to know the name of the animation, which I can pass to this method of my AnimClass in order to call it because without a name, I can't call the desired animation in my method, but open the script and so on, judging by what I read, it's generally stupid and not right
How do adequate people work with this in order to comply with all these rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally code the animations into the Player.cs or Npc.cs, the Animator component is already a really complex Script, so there is no need to complicate things and write new scripts for handling the animations.

I know that you want to write clean code, but the Animator component already provides you the methods you need, you simply have to write a script like the following:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    public Animator animator;
    private bool isJumping;
    private bool isRunning;

    private void Update(){
       isJumping = true; //obviusly you need to write some logic
       isRunning = false; //obviusly you need to write some logic
      
       animator.SetBool("Jump", isJumping);
       animator.SetBool("Run", isRunning);
    }
}
```

If you don't know what `animator.SetBool` is, watch a youtube video about the Animator conditions.