# How do I change animations in unity correctly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've read a lot of options, but I still couldn't find the right one. I ask you to tell me how to do it better. Briefly about my situation: a 3D game. There is a player who has 3 types of animation: idle, run, jump. The player has a rigidbody + capsule collider. There are also scripts. I am faced with the problem that my player jumps normally, but sometimes the jump animation itself does not start or stops immediately. How do I make everything work as it should? According to my logic, if the player does not move and does not fall somewhere or jump, then the animation is idle. If it goes, but does not fall or jump, then the animation runs, but the jump when you press the space bar. What did I do wrong? I'm still learning.

```
//ScriptPlayerMove
private void Awake()
{
    _rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    _playerCheckGround = GetComponent<PlayerCheckGround>();
    _playerAnimatorController = GetComponent<PlayerAnimationController>();
    _mainCameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
    _playerInputActions = new PlayerInputActions();
    _playerInputActions.Player.Enable();
    _playerInputActions.Player.Jump.started += Jump;

        
}

public void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector2 inputVector = _playerInputActions.Player.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    Vector3 movement = _mainCameraTransform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(inputVector.x, 0, inputVector.y));
    _rigidBody.velocity = new Vector3(movement.x * _speedMove, _rigidBody.velocity.y, movement.z * _speedMove);

    if (movement.magnitude > 0.1f) 
    {
        Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(movement.x, 0, movement.z));
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, toRotation, Time.fixedDeltaTime * 10f);

        if (_playerCheckGround.IsGround())
        {
            if (_rigidBody.velocity.y > 0) return;
            _playerAnimatorController.SwitchAnimation("Run");

        }


    }
    else
    {
        if (_playerCheckGround.IsGround())
        {
            if (_rigidBody.velocity.y > 0) return;

            _playerAnimatorController.SwitchAnimation("Idle");
        }

    }

}


public void Jump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    if (context.started)
    {
        if (_playerCheckGround.IsGround())
        {
            _rigidBody.AddForce(0, _jumpForce, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);

            _playerAnimatorController.SwitchAnimation("Jump");
        }
   
    }

}



//Script PlayerAnimationController

private Animator _animator;
private void Start()
{
    _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}



public void SwitchAnimation(string nameAnim)
{
    switch (nameAnim)
    {
        case "Idle":
            {
                _animator.SetBool("CanIdle", true);
                _animator.SetBool("CanJump", false);
                _animator.SetBool("CanRun", false);

                break;
            }

        case "Run":
            {
                _animator.SetBool("CanIdle", false);
                _animator.SetBool("CanJump", false);
                _animator.SetBool("CanRun", true);

                break;
            }
        case "Jump":
            {
                _animator.SetBool("CanIdle", false);
                _animator.SetBool("CanJump", true);
                _animator.SetBool("CanRun", false);

                break;
            }

    }
}


//playerCheckGround script

 [SerializeField] private float _rayDistance;
CapsuleCollider _capsuleCollider;


public bool PlayerStayOnGround;


private void Start()
{
    _capsuleCollider = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
}


public bool IsGround()
{

    Vector3 rayOrigin = _capsuleCollider.transform.position - new Vector3(0, _capsuleCollider.height / 2f - _capsuleCollider.radius, 0);
    Vector3 rayDirection = Vector3.down;
    Ray ray = new Ray(rayOrigin, rayDirection);
    float maxRayDistance = _rayDistance;
    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * maxRayDistance, Color.green);  
    bool hitSomething = Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo, maxRayDistance);
    PlayerStayOnGround = hitSomething;

    return PlayerStayOnGround;
}
```

Comment: Is this still the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77856410/how-do-i-switch-animations-in-unity-correctly ...? If not might still be worth to at least mention where you come from ;)

Comment: there I asked in terms of how to implement it so that the code conforms to the principles of SOLID, but here the problem with the change is in the logic somewhere

Comment: well if you jump you set the animation to run.... because in fixed update if theres movement you set it to run..

Comment: we can't tell as we don't see your animator transitions .. possible that you enter the jump animation but immediately transition away to either running or idle ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idk all the details so it's hard to get a solution but try this:

1. Don't invoke animations in FixedUpdate, this method it's normally used for physics so avoid to use it for other things, use instead the Update method
2. In your Animator window check if the transitions have exit time and delay time, if u want this animations to execute inmediatly deactivate this options